# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence for pd df & np.array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, valueerror

I get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence` for line `beta[i]=np.cov(rm[i],ra[i])` when `i=0`, which means the for loop starts running and stops there, so I get the first values of `rm` and `ra` vectors but not the first value of `beta`. 
`agg_df` is a pd df with 50 rows and 1 column called `mean`.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np
path ="C:\\Users\\sharon\\Desktop\\financial mathematics\\sadna"
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df_list = [(pd.read_csv(f, encoding = "utf-8", header = None,usecols = [3], nrows = 470, ).assign(filename = f)) for f in all_files]
final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
final_df[3]= final_df[3].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
agg_df = final_df.groupby(['filename']).agg(['mean'])
agg_df.columns=['mean']
agg_df.index=range(50)
ra=np.ones(shape=(50))
beta=np.ones(shape=(50))
rm=np.ones(shape=(50))
for i in range(0,50):
    rm[i]=np.mean(agg_df['mean'])
    ra[i]=agg_df.loc[i,'mean']
    beta[i]=np.cov(rm[i],ra[i])
```

---

**edit:**
the data in `agg_df` is the average on precentage of daily change in price of 50 stocks, each row is one stock.
[image: in the image there are the types of my varaibles]

Comment: Can you give more detail about your data, maybe upload a little example, so we can really try to copy your conditions? What exactly is your intended output? Especially the datatypes of all the variables would be important here (my first assumption: there's something wrong with that).

Comment: If you didn't read the page regarding [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](minimal reproducible example) till now, I recommend to do so, since it is really helping others to boil down, what is causing your troubles.

Comment: see my edition for the question. about the link in your comment - "page not found" so I could not read.

Comment: Now I see, the link is messed up. Here it is again [-->Click<--](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Regarding your data: Is it right, that df_list is a list of dataframes? Ho do the dataframes look like?

Comment: yes but I got this into how agg_df looks like right now so what's relevant is only agg_df.

Comment: So how should ra and rm look like, what is their meaning? Appearantly the problem is in the line with beta, where np.cov expects 2 arrays as arguments, but you give only 2 scalars to it. If you give `np.cov(rm,ra)` , at least it's working, however I don't know, if that is giving the intended output.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you try to assign an `np.array` element with something that is not compatible with that element's shape. For example assigning an element with shape `(2, 2)` to an array element with shape `(1,)`.

Now let's examine the shapes. `beta[i]` is a scalar (shape `()`), while `np.cov()` returns a covariance matrix, of shape at least `(1, 1)`, which is not compatible with `beta[i]`, hence you get the error.

You should rethink the shapes of your arrays to match with the intended computation.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
beta[i]=np.cov(rm[i],ra[i])
```

`beta`, `rm` and `ra` are all (50,) arrays.  So `rm[i]` etc is a scalar, and `beta[i]` can only hold **one** number.

If I give `np.cov` to scalars, I get a warning, and (2,2) array:

```
In [104]: np.cov(1.23,2.323)                                                                                               
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  #!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2455: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  c *= np.true_divide(1, fact)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2455: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  c *= np.true_divide(1, fact)
Out[104]: 
array([[nan, nan],
       [nan, nan]])
```

That array cannot be assigned to a `beta[i]`.

Why are you using `np.cov` with scalar arguments.  That doesn't make sense.